# Python convert a vector into inverse frequencies

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So given this `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1])  

# len(vector) == 12
# 2 x ones, 4 x two, 6 x three
```

How can I convert this into a vector of inverse frequencies?

Such that for each value, the output contains 1 divided by the frequency of that value:

```
array([0.16, 0.33, 0.33, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.33, 0.33, 0.16])
```

Comment: but this is not a vector of probabilities.  By definition, `Probabilities` must sum to one. Else it's wrong to call it as probabilities

Comment: @kmario23 Fair point. Forgive my terminology. What should i call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This essentially requires a grouping operation, which `numpy` isn't great at... but `pandas` is. You can do this with `groupby` + `transform` + `count`, and divide the result by the `len`gth of `vector`.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(vector)
vector = (s.groupby(s).transform('count') / len(s)).values
```

```
vector
array([ 0.16666667,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,
        0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,
        0.33333333,  0.16666667])
```

Comment: NIce, I knew there must be a nice way. I just couldn't find it! Thanks COLDSPEED!

Answer (score 4):

**[Update to a general one]**

How about this one using `np.histogram`:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1])
_u, _l = np.unique(l, return_inverse=True)
np.histogram(_l, bins=np.arange(_u.size+1))[0][_l] / _l.size
```

Comment: In general, `numpy` way is much faster than `pandas` way.

Comment: Cool, great answer! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to first determine the frequency of each element. Then create an intermediate mapping dict which will contain key as the element and value as the frequency. Finally using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to transform the array to your desired format

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> v = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]) 
>>> freq_dict = Counter(v)
```

At this point the `freq_dict` will contains frequency of each element like

```
>>> freq_dict
>>> Counter({3: 6, 2: 4, 1: 2})
```

Next build a probability dict of the format `element: probability`, using dict comprehension

```
>>> prob_dict = dict((k,round(val/len(v),3)) for k, val in freq_dict.items())
>>> prob_dict
>>> {1: 0.167, 2: 0.333, 3: 0.5}
```

Finally using `numpy.vectorize` to get your desired output

```
>>> out = np.vectorize(prob_dict.get)(v)
```

This will produce:

```
>>> out
>>> array([ 0.167,  0.333,  0.333,  0.5, 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.5,
           0.5, 0.333, 0.333, 0.167])
```